# PyTorch: Using Subset on Datapipe

Tags: pytorch

In PyTorch, if you want to take only some of a Dataset, you use Subset.  For example: I want only the first 1000 records.

Now that PyTorch has migrated from Dataset to Datapipe, what is the right way to use only part of the data?

Answer (score 1):

**Header** is precisely designed for this use case.

You could simply do this to get the first 1000 samples in your datapipe,

```
dp = dp.header(1000)
```

Documentation : https://pytorch.org/data/main/generated/torchdata.datapipes.iter.Header.html#torchdata.datapipes.iter.Header

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://pytorch.org/data/main/generated/torchdata.datapipes.iter.Filter.html#torchdata.datapipes.iter.Filter), the answer would be a `Filter`.

#### Stateful filter

```py
def make_filter(num_items: int) -> Callable[[Any], bool]:
   count = 0
   def f(_: Any) -> bool:
        nonlocal count 
        count += 1
        return count <= num_items
   return f

filter_fn = make_filter(3)
print(list(map(filter_fn, range(5)))
# [True, True, True, False, False]
```

Comment: Filter can be used to filter by looking at each data and determining if you want it.  Subset does something different: I just want the first 1000.  Filter can't do that, as the filter fn isn't stateful.

Comment: You can make a stateful filter, see edit. If your intention is to make a literal subset of the data, what's stopping you from constructing a datapipe on the subset origin though?

Comment: How do I use a datapipe to subset another datapipe?

Comment: how do you make a datapipe in the first place?